# Where I can find openssl iOS 7 libcrypto.a and libssl.a static library for arm64 architecture

Tags: openssl, arm64

I need libcrypto.a and libssl.a static library for arm64 bit architecture in iOS 7 to build and run a project.

Comment: If you want, you can also build static library for ARM64. Please read README files to follow the instruction.

Answer (score 19):

You can build it from source with this build script: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link.I am able to build the script and i have got the libcrypto.a, libssl.a files. But the problem hear is i am getting the error saying "openssl/bio.h file not found" when i am building the application in Xcode5. Can u please help me on this issue?

Comment: You must include the header files in you HEADER_SEARCH_PATH

Comment: As of writing this, that script is broken and unable to compile the openssl library. Both the old 1.0.2 version and the newest (as of writing this) version 1.1.1a of the openssl library fail to be compiled by the script (fails at running the configure script), at least using the current clang/xcode. The script hasn't been updated in two years, and it's not obvious how it could be fixed. Any ideas, or alternatives?